# Spring @Resource Handling

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, weblogic, jndi

I'm having trouble with a field annotated as `@Resource` in a Spring bean. What I have:

A field, with setter method, annotated `@Resource`

```
@Resource
private URL someUrl;

public void setSomeUrl(URL someUrl) {
    this.someUrl = someUrl;
}
```

An `<env-entry>` tag in my deployment descriptor (web.xml)

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>someUrl</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.net.URL</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>http://somedomain.net/some/path</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

The application fails to start with a `BeanCreationException`, which I dont' expect because I don't necessarily want spring to inject a Spring-managed bean. I want Spring to process `@Resource` and retrieve the JNDI resource.

This is Spring 2.5.6SEC03 and the bean itself is annotated `@Service` for autowiring into other `@Component` instances. Servlet container in this case is Tomcat 7 but will ultimately be deployed onto Weblogic 10, so while I'd like ideally for a solution to work on both, Weblogic is the must-have.

Am I misusing this feature in Spring 2.5? In general? Is there some bit I'm missing? Something I misunderstand about JNDI? All help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using Spring Stereotype annotations, (`@Service`, `@Component`...), then you are probably including in your spring configuration the `<context:component-scan />` element to pick them up.  It is fine to do this, but it will automatically register a [`CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) with the application context, [as stated just above the second note in this link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config).

The issue with including the `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` is that Spring handles the `@Resource` annotation and will attempt to inject beans from its application context.  You can register your own `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` bean and tell Spring to allow direct JNDI access to these `@Resource`'s by configuring the bean by setting the `alwaysUseJndiLookup` property to `true`.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">
  <property name="alwaysUseJndiLookup" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Pay attention to the note in the linked documentation:

> NOTE: A default CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor will be registered by the "context:annotation-config" and "context:component-scan" XML tags. Remove or turn off the default annotation configuration there if you intend to specify a custom CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor bean definition!

Comment: Great, this totally worked! I also discovered that you can force CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor to do a JNDI lookup by sprcifying a value for "mappedName" in the annotation body. All that said, and after the work put into this, I learned that our standard corporate deployment process won't support multiple deployment descriptors. I'm supposed to use the same one across all deployments. So, this approach won't work.