# Queue creation in Spring Environment

Tags: spring, jboss, jms, spring-jms

I am new to Spring Jms and i studied how to work with spring and jboss to create queues and work with them. I want to know how queues are created when configured with JndiObjectFactoryBean spring configuration.

Do we need to write some xml configurations for creating Queues?.I have seen various examples of writing queue configurations in file and placing in deploy folder of jboss.So when working with Spring do we need to write those configurations?

Please Help me i am stuck.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you work with a JMS broker that is accessed through JNDI, you only need to make sure that Spring is going to be able to resolve a String representing the `javax.jms.Destination` to the actual Destination.

Spring does that with `DestinationResolver`. Since you have configured Spring to connect to your JMS broker, you must have a JNDI configuration somewhere (either through the use of `jndi.properties` or some other form). And you can easily create a `JndiTemplate` with it if that's not the case already

Once you have that, you need to define a bean as follows, assuming the `JndiTemplate` bean is available with name `jndiTemplate`:

```
@Bean
public JndiDestinationResolver destinationResolver() {
   JndiDestinationResolver destinationResolver = new JndiDestinationResolver();
   destinationResolver.setJndiTemplate(jndiTemplate());
   return destinationResolver;
}
```

or

```
<bean id="destinationResolver"
      class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate"/>
</bean>
```

Then you need to configure this destinationResolver instead of the default. You can do that on `JmsTemplate` and on the message listener container (check the `destinationResolver` or `destination-resolver` property).

The name of your queue or topic is the jndi entry. Chekc the JNDI name that you have used in JBoss to lookup it from your Spring-based code.

Answer (score 1):

When you work with some JEE container it would be better, if you rely on its options: JDBC, JMS etc. Hance in your case you should configure `Queue` and `ConnectionFactory` using JBOSS configuration.

From Spring application you just need to get reference to those objects from JNDI. Seems for like `@Resource` should be enough for case of `@Configuration` or any `@Component` service.

Here is some answer how to configure Spring to get deal with JNDI in case of Annotation configuration: [Spring @Resource Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931491/spring-resource-handling)